# Trouble accessing Wordpress site on Azure Apps with custom domain - database connection error

Tags: php, wordpress, azure

Wordpress hosted on azure apps with custom domain configured giving error in connecting database...
The website is currently giving an error in connecting the database while accessing with a custom domain configured. When we access using domain.azurewebsite.com it shows properly. But when i try to access using custom domain it throws database connection error.

I tried to enable wp debug from wp-config.php but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated the URL of the site? https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/changing-the-site-url/#changing-the-url-directly-in-the-database

You can do it directly via: `https://<sitename>.azurewebsites.net/phpmyadmin`

Comment: i changed the site url from phpmyadmin but it also did not work